# How to run a command (1000 times) that requires two different types of input files

Tags: bash, modularity

I have calculated directed modularity by means of DirectedLouvain (https://github.com/nicolasdugue/DirectedLouvain). I am now trying to test the significance of the values obtained, by means of a null model. To do it I need to run 1000 times one of the commands of DirectedLouvain over 1000 different input files.

Following @ KamilCuk recomendations I have used this code that takes the 1000 *.txt input files and generates 1000 *.bin files and 1000 *.weights files. It worked perfectly:

```
find -type f -name '*.txt' |
while IFS= read -r file; do
   file_no_extension=${file##*/};
   file_no_extension=${file_no_extension%%.*}
   ./convert -i "$file" -o "$file_no_extension".bin -w "$file_no_extension".weights
done
```

Now I am trying to use another command that takes these two types of files (*.bin and *.weights) and generates *.tree files. I have tried this with no success:

```
find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.bin -o -iname \*.weights \) | 
while IFS= read -r file; do
   file_no_extension=${file##*/};
   file_no_extension=${file_no_extension%%.*}
   ./community "$file.bin" -l -1 -w "$file.weights" > "$file_no_extension".tree
done
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please show 3 representative filenames from your 1,000 filenames and the corresponding commands that you would want to run on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find all files with that extension.
2. For each file

   1. Extract the filename without exntesion
   2. Run the command

So:

```
find -type f -name '*.ext' |
while IFS= read -r file; do
   file_no_extension=${file##*/};
   file_no_extension=${file_no_extension%%.*}
   ./convert -i "$file" -o "$file_no_extension".bin -w "$file_no_extension".weights
done

// with find:
find -type f -name '*.ext' -exec sh -c 'f=$(basename "$1" .ext); ./convert -i "$1" -o "$f".bin -w "$f".weights' _ {} \;

// with xargs:
find -type f -name '*.ext' |
xargs -d '\n' -n1 sh -c 'f=$(basename "$1" .ext); ./convert -i "$1" -o "$f".bin -w "$f".weights' _
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **GNU Parallel** to run your jobs in parallel across all your CPU cores like this:

```
parallel convert -i {} -o {.}.bin -w {.}.weights ::: input*.txt
```

Initially, you may like to do a *"dry run"* that shows what it would do without actually doing anything:

```
parallel --dry-run convert -i {} -o {.}.bin -w {.}.weights ::: input*.txt
```

---

If you get errors about the argument list being too long because you have too many files, you can feed their names in on `stdin` like this instead:

```
find . -name "input*txt" -print0 | parallel -0 convert -i {} -o {.}.bin -w {.}.weights
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to list your files and execute a command on all of them:

```
find -name '*.ext' -exec ./runThisExecutable '{}' \;
```

If you have `a.ext` and `b.ext` in a directory, this will run `./runThisExecutable a.ext` and `./runThisExecutable b.ext`.

To test whether it identifies the right files, you can run it without `-exec` so it only prints the filenames:

```
find -name '*.ext'
./a.ext
./b.ext
```

Comment: `The specific command is` Please edit your question and add such important details  in it. Does `file.bin` has `.ext` extension removed?