# Execute a command multiple times whose input files have different extensions

Tags: bash, modularity

I trying to calculate some directed modularity estimates by means of [DirectedLouvain](https://github.com/nicolasdugue/DirectedLouvain). I have to use a command `./community *.bin -l -1 -w *.weights > *.tree` that takes two different types of input files (*.bin and *.weights) and generates *.tree files. I want it to run over 1000 *.bin files and 1000 *.weights files that I have stored in a folder. Base on a previous recomendation by @KamilCuk, I have tried this with no success:

```
find -type f -name *.bin -o -name *.weights | 
while IFS= read -r file; do
   file_no_extension=${file##*/};
   file_no_extension=${file_no_extension%%.*}
   ./community "$file.bin" -l -1 -w "$file.weights" > "$file_no_extension".tree
done
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to add a test for the filename if it match `*.bin` then assign to a variable same goes to `*.weights` but with a different name variable, so your `community` command  it will be straight forward which is which.

Comment: How is this different from your last question please? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62596795/2836621

Comment: @Jetchisel I have no idea of bash programming. Do you mean something like `find -type f -name '*.bin' -o -name '*.weights' |
while IFS= read -r file; do
   file_bin=${file##*bin};
   file_weights=${file##*weights};
   file_no_extension=${file_no_extension%%.*}
   ./community "$file.bin"   -l -1 -w "$file.weights" > "$file_no_extension".tree
done`

Comment: @shasha I added it as a possible answer instead. It's hard to read code in comments.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have clarified it to be more precise.

Comment: @TedLyngmo they are pairs (eg. input1.bin, input1.weights; upto input1000.bin,input1000.weights)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the files with the extension `.bin` have a corresponding `.weights` file, this is probably what you should do:

```
#!/bin/bash

find -type f -iname '*.bin' |
while IFS= read -r binfile; do
    file_no_extension=${binfile%%.bin}

    weightsfile="$file_no_extension".weights
    treefile="$file_no_extension".tree

    ./community "$binfile" -l -1 -w "$weightsfile" > "$treefile"
done
```

This will place the `.tree` file in the same directory as the `.bin` and `.weights` file.

Comment: That made the trick!

Comment: @shasha Great! :-)